# Как решить проблему с расчетом высоты элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть чат, который я загружаю из БД посредством AJAX, я автоматически скролю страничку вниз после загрузки этого чата:

```
$('.chat').scrollTop($('.chat')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Всё идеально работает пока нет изображений. Расчет высоты с картинками проходит криво, ибо они могут отрендериться в бразуере после того, как сработает $(document).ready(). Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А если при отправке, заодно и сохранять размеры картинок строго в пикселях? А загружать блоки с картинками, с теми же пикселями. Когда захотят, тогда и загрузятся.

Comment: Посмотрите в этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript - думаю поможет

Answer (score 1):

Код внутри `$(document).ready()` будет выполняться непосредственно после готовности DOM, не дожидаясь полной загрузки изображений.

Вам поможет
`$(window).on('load', function () {})` 
т.к. код, написанный внутри такой конструкции, начнёт работу когда будет готов весь DOM включая изображения.